# Open file with spaces in filename using Ubuntu for Windows (WSL) - cmd.exe

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows 10 Fall Creator's Update (version 1703) with Ubuntu app installed (WSL), which can natively launch Windows programs using `cmd.exe /C start ""`.

My goal is to open files in `/mnt/d` using the default windows application for a file.

It works for me most of the times except when I want to open file names with spaces in them. In those cases, it just opens `cmd.exe` window and prompt in the equivalent windows directory path where the file belongs. It does not open the file in default application.

For example, if I have files `courses.py` and `a file name with spaces.py` in `/mnt/d/files`

`cmd.exe /C start courses.py` - opens `courses.py` in VS Code.

`cmd.exe /C start a\ file\ name\ with\ spaces.py` - opens `cmd.exe` with prompt at `D:\files`

Am I providing the file name in WSL incorrectly?

Comment: `Start "" "a\ file\ name\ with\ spaces.py"`

Comment: @Compo, a non-empty window title is generally better. Otherwise changes to console properties are persisted to the default settings in "HKCU\Console", which affects every console window that doesn't override the default property value (e.g. window size/position, screen buffer size, font). If you use "Python Script" as the window title, then modified console properties will instead be stored in "HKCU\Console\Python Script".

Comment: @eryksun, I used the empty title for one reason alone, to illustrate the usage the OP reported in their first paragraph.

Comment: @Compo thanks for the solution. Works for me.

Comment: @eryksun I will make a bash function which populates it with the name of the file/directory I am trying to open.

Answer (score 0):

@Compo provided the solution in the comments:

`cmd.exe /C start "" "a\ file\ name\ with\ spaces.py"`

Since I use [wsl-terminal](https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal), I got past this issue by using this neat built-in command:

`cmdtool wstartex <file|url>`